# Screen Resoltuions for windows 8 tablets and phone 8?

Tags: windows-8

Can anybody please tell me if the tablet app can run on windows phone 8 without any UI changes?

I mean that if tablet app can exactly run on windows phone 8 and the tablet screen will fit into phone 8.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking whether Windows RT apps can run on the phone unchanged (binary compatibility), or merely whether their UI will fit on the phone. If you're just asking about UI, the answer is "probably not" because Windows Phone 8's maximum resolution (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_8)) is 1280x768, which is still less than the Windows RT *minimum* resolution of 1366x768 (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT)).

Comment: I'm going to guess that you will have to rewrite the interface.  Some concepts in Windows 8 don't make sense on a phone (like the "snapped" view).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 resolutions are either 15:9 or 16:9 and usually held in portrait. All Windows RT tablets are 16:9, and usually held in landscape.

So any way you look at it you will probably have to redesign your UI.

I wouldn't recommend reusing the XAML either - you can reuse lots of code-behind or ui-less classes though if you put them in a Portable Library (works with WP7, WinRT and presumably 8 too)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 apps are build keeping these things in mind.

1) It should support at least 10.6 inch screen with a minimum resolution of 1366*768 and so forth
The app UI are designed keeping in mind the wide space grid available to them

In windows phone ,the screen size is 4.3 inch so you can imagine they won't actually fit in